# package structure in Spring,Entity vs Model vs Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

how do you define what is model or entity in MVC?

most of my Spring codes had package strucure like his:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-example/

I have my view, my controller, my dao and "the model" for the dao

but I try to learn thymeleaf and found this:
https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleafexamples-stsm

there is no "model"package, he call it entity, it is an entity but..

then I thought...oh wait a minute...what is the definition of entiy and model?
similar to this question:
[Entity vs Model vs View Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26563444/entity-vs-model-vs-view-model)

so 
what is your package structre, do you call it model or entity?
do you have maybe examples of the packagenames/structure of your spring projects?

Comment: Model refers fields bind at UI side while entity represent that fields at DB side like Hibernate have.

Comment: @w3Charlie is your question finally resolved?

Answer (score 13):

Literally, a `Model` is a class for representing POJO. `Entity` - has relation to DB.

Sometimes they are mixed together, like:

```
package net.lelyak.edu.entity;

@Entity
public class User extends BaseEntity {
// fields + get/set
```

The structure depends on a convention of your project or team.

If it is your personal project you can fully decide which package structure you want to follow.

Here is some way which I did for my spring training:

[image]

However, for your own purpose, you can fully decide how to manage packages, following are also legit:

[image]

The main idea is that no strict borders for it.

For the personal project, it has to be a convenience for you.
When you collaborating with others on the same project, you have to agree on it together.

Comment: Good example for package-by-layer and package-by-feature.

Answer (score 7):

My Spring projects most have a package structure like below. This structure is my base structure for `dao`, `services`, `implementations`, `view` and `util`. Sure the structure can change and all that depends on what you have to develop.

```
com.companyName.appName.config -> 
I use config for my classes which are annotated with @Configuration.

com.companyName.appName.dao.model -> 
I use dao.model for all my entities from the DB.

com.companyName.appName.dao.repository -> 
I use dao.repository for all the repositories used with spring-data-jpa.

com.companyName.appName.dao.repository.impl -> 
I use dao.repository.impl for all customized implementations of repositories. 
For example to autowire the entityManager.

com.companyName.appName.service -> 
I use service for all my service interfaces

com.companyName.appName.service.impl -> 
I use service.impl for all my implementations of services

com.companyName.appName.controller -> 
I use controller for all my controllers.

com.companyName.appName.view.model -> 
I use view.model for all my frontend specific models which are no enitites.

com.companyName.appName.view.form -> 
I use view.form for all my frontend specific forms which has to be submitted and validated.

com.companyName.appName.util -> 
I use util for utility stuff.
```

I hope this gives you a short overview how I structure my packages for spring-boot applications. But everybody like to have its own naming. So its very difficult to make it general.

Answer (score 0):

In my projects I like to call `DAOs` objects simply `data` or `entity` and objects thats should be returned to the UI `presentation` in your case they are called `model`. I'm doing it mainly because of during long time already using thymeleaf + Spring-Boot which makes old  fashion `model` terminology redundant:

- `com.company.appName.data` or `com.company.appName.entity`
- `com.company.appName.presentation`

But in a case of big projects with more complex structure sometimes `presentation` objets good to place together with business logic:

- `com.company.appName.data` or `com.company.appName.entity`
- `com.company.appName.account`

  - `com.company.appName.account.service` - business logic
  - `com.company.appName.account.presentation` - UI data objects