# ASP.Net MVVM and MVC Services vs Models

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core, mvvm

I apologize in advance if my question is vague and / or not constructed well. I am just getting started exploring ASP.NET Core MVC and Razor Pages (MVVM) and I am confused as to what is the difference between a model and a service. What questions should I ask myself before deciding if I need a new model or a new service. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe following thread is really nice to understand. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26563444/entity-vs-model-vs-view-model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question because after posting this question I found a great explanation of what the differences are between a model and a service by reading the MVC Basics chapter in this great book - https://nbarbettini.gitbooks.io/little-asp-net-core-book/content/chapters/mvc-basics/